# Django Formset Validation - Sum Values in Formset

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, formset, django-validation

I have a page containing a Django form, then below it a formset (dynamic number of rows).

In the top form is a "total length" field, and each row of the formset below contains a "length" field.  I need to validate that the sum of the lengths submitted for each row of the formset is <= the "total length" field on the single form at the top.

I don't think I can do this using the normal form clean method on the form that makes up the formset, since that has no scope to get the values from the other forms in the formset.  I guess I could do it in the view instead, but is this the best way?

Edit:

Resolved by putting validation logic in view and looping through formset:

```
if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
    total_sample_length = form.cleaned_data['total_length']
        if total_sample_length:
            sum_segment_lengths = 0
            for segment_form in formset:
                sum_segment_lengths += segment_form.cleaned_data['length']
            if sum_segment_lengths > total_sample_length:
                for segment_form in formset:
                    segment_form.add_error('length', 'Sum of Segment Lengths must be <= Total Length!')
                return render(request, template, {...})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a view to handle this, and a custom clean method on the top form to raise an error on total length.

On the view, you should evaluate each formset form, and get a total length.

Then check that with the top form, raising an error on the clean if the size does not fit your dimensions.

Comment: Is there a way to carry out validation of a field's values between two consecutive (inline formset) rows by iterating over them? For example, if I have a field `price`, I want to check if the `price` fields' values (between two consecutive rows) do not differ by more than 10% (+/-). In order to avoid iterating over a large number of formset rows every time new data is saved (as updates), I have added a **boolean field** that would be marked `True` once  a particular row has passed thru the said validation & would not be checked again. Could you give me a headup how to do such an iteration?

Comment: Did you consider a javascript validation?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Using javascript (or jquery) was to be my final calling!! But I wanted to know if something is available within the Django realm. I have a number of fields with diverse conditions to check, and though I am somewhat comfortable with jquery, was thinking if Python (Django) native would be a better bet.

Comment: Happy to inform that FINALLY I have been able to do it using BaseInlineFormset using `clean()` method.